# cocos2dx Multi touch and touch

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

everyone! I have trouble with combination in one scene multi touch and one touch with. So let me describe my problem step by step.

I use cocos2dx( for android ), So I have scene, on this scene I add layer [Pan Zoom Layer](https://github.com/growingdever/cocos2d-x-panzoomlayer/blob/master/Classes/PanZoomLayer.h) for scroll and zoom. next, I add new layer(Game Layer) on PanZoomLayer. I need catch click on Game Layer(on this layer located my game things) I try to do so, using pattern observer,I have done PanZoom Layer by "Subject" my Game Layer - "Observer", and in PanZoomLayer Have created enum EVENTS, and struct touchEvent

```
enum EVENTS{
   EVENT_ONCE_CLICK,
   EVENT_MOVE,
   ANOTHER,
};

struct  touchEvent {
  EVENTS eventName;
};
```

and created in class PanZoomLayer field m_events :

```
std::stack<EVENTS> m_events;
```

and on onTouchesBegan add such code

```
if (_touches.size() == 1) {
    m_events.push(EVENTS::EVENT_ONCE_CLICK);
}
else {
    m_events.push(EVENTS::ANOTHER);
}
```

in onTouchesMoved add such code in branch if _touches.size() == 1:

```
Vec2 curTouchPosition = Director::getInstance()->convertToGL(touch->getLocationInView());
    Vec2 prevTouchPosition = Director::getInstance()->convertToGL(touch->getPreviousLocationInView());
    Vec2 deltaPosition = curTouchPosition - prevTouchPosition;
    float pos = curTouchPosition.distance(prevTouchPosition);
    if (fabs(pos) < 0.5f) {
        m_events.push(EVENTS::EVENT_ONCE_CLICK);
    }
    else {
        m_events.push(EVENTS::ANOTHER);
    }
```

an onTouchesEnded, add such code :

```
if (m_events.empty())
     return;
 EVENTS ev = m_events.top();
while (!m_events.empty()) {
    m_events.pop();
}
if (ev == EVENTS::EVENT_ONCE_CLICK) {
 //    MessageBox("once click", "title");
     Touch *touch = (Touch *)_touches.at(0);
     Vec2 position = touch->getLocation();
     notifyClick(position);
}
```

where notifyClick :

```
std::shared_ptr<CSceneSession> sessionShared = m_session.lock();
if (sessionShared)
    sessionShared->clickOnScene(point);
```

So I enter in game cycle : game scene -> transition on menu scene -> game scene...... in start it great work, but after some time ( on difference devices - different time) game begin strange behavior : buggy,

Could you help me please? Thanks for any idea and suggestions.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I think you may be overcomplicating it.

Comment: Thank you for your attention! I Solved my problem in the following way: I remove scheduleUpdateForTarget in method onEnter and remove unscheduleAllForTarget in method onExit and remove method update.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved my problem in the following way: I remove scheduleUpdateForTarget in method onEnter and remove unscheduleAllForTarget in method onExit and remove method update.
Thank you for your attention!